# Difference between pop and [:-1] for lists, and different behaviour for s[:-1] when s is a string or a list

Tags: python, string, list

I've been practicing on leetcode recently and have just done the question "Combination Sum" (abridged, the full statement can be found at https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/).

> Given an array of distinct integers candidates and a target integer
> target, return a list of all unique combinations of candidates where
> the chosen numbers sum to target. You may return the combinations in
> any order.
>
> The same number may be chosen from candidates an unlimited number of
> times. Two combinations are unique if the frequency of at least one of
> the chosen numbers is different.

I solved the problem correctly using a simple backtracking method which builds up a solution partial and then appends it to an array ans using the following helper function (partial is a list)

```
def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        ans = []
        def helper(candidates, target, partial):
            if target == 0:
                ans.append(partial[:])
                return
            if target < 0:
                return
            for i in range(0,len(candidates)):
                partial.append(candidates[i])
                helper(candidates[i:], target-candidates[i], partial)
                partial.pop()
        
        candidates.sort()
        helper(candidates,target,[])
        return ans
```

This code works and I'm happy with it. However, if I change the final line to:

```
partial = partial[:-1]
```

The solution no longer works. In particular, elements don't get removed as I would like, and my ans array ends up getting solutions with huge numbers of elements which are incorrect. Intuitively I expected these to serve the same purpose of removing the last element from partial.

I suspect it has something to do with references and list slicing that I'm missing. Why didn't I have this problem when I solved the leetcode problem combinations of a phone number (see https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/) which asks to enumerate all possible strings that come from a digit-letter phone mapping, given a string of digits?

Here I used the same helper function structure:

```
def letterCombinations(self, digits: str) -> List[str]:
        ans = []
        MAPPING = ('0', '1', "abc", "def", 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz')
        def helper(s, partial_sol):
            if len(s) == 0:
                ans.append(partial_sol)
                return
            else:
                for i in MAPPING[int(s[0])]:
                    partial_sol = partial_sol + i
                    helper(s[1:], partial_sol)
                    partial_sol = partial_sol[:-1]
        if len(digits) == 0:
            return ans
        helper(digits, "")
        return(ans)
```

and my solution was correct. Note though that I have used the [:-1] method which didn't work with the first problem on lists, but is with this problem on strings. So I can see that whatever is going on is different for strings versus lists (as in the phone number problem, partial is a string rather than a list), I just don't know exactly what it is, or why.

In short, my questions are:

1. Why does my solution for Combination Sum not work when I change from popping partial to:

```
partial = partial[:-1]
```

2. Why does that solution not work for Combination Sum (which uses lists) but it does for Letters from a Phone Number (which uses strings)?

Comment: Strings don't _have_ `.pop`, they're immutable, so it's not clear what comparison you're making there. `[:-1]` makes a new list, containing everything but the last value of the list it was created from.

Comment: Sorry I know strings don't have `pop`, the comparison was the fact that using `[:-1]` worked in the string problem, but not the list problem. So it seems to me that whatever the `[:-1]` is exactly doing seems to give me different outcomes for string and list.

Comment: Your code is quite confusing (for example what is `ans`, where is it coming from, and why do you keep making copies of your lists?) and I'm not sure what you're asking for help with. Strings are not lists, so they don't have `pop`. You're never returning anything so it looks like you're trying to modify some sort of global object that you're not showing us.

Comment: `partial = partial[:-1]` works for strings _and_ lists, because you assign the result back over the full-length version. The behaviour's exactly the same. The difference is you're not _returning_ the new value, so the _caller_ still has a reference to the previous one.

Comment: I've re-edited with my full solution, hopefully its more understandable

Comment: Fundamentally the problem is that your solution treats both `ans` _and_ `partial` as globals (or rather `nonlocal`s, as they're closed over), but you've obscured that by having the latter passed as a parameter. You _can't_ make that mistake with a string, because it's immutable. `partial = partial[:-1]` is a _local_ reassignment of a _new_ list, whereas `partial.pop()` mutates the shared list. Using something like https://pythontutor.com/ might make it clearer what's going on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that makes sense, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct it has to do with references and `list` slicing.

`partial.pop()` modifies the `list` bound to `partial` in-place.

`partial = partial[:-1]` makes a shallow copy of the `list`, and *rebinds* `partial` to the new `list`.

This is an important distinction because rebinding doesn't change any other aliases referring to the original `list`, which includes the caller's binding to that same `list`. To make the two behave almost equivalently (`pop` is much more *efficient*, and unlike slicing, will error on an empty `list`) you can use:

```
partial[:] = partial[:-1]
```

which reassigns the *contents* of the original `list` to the contents of the shallow copy, or, with equivalent (possibly slightly better) performance than `pop`:

```
# Errors on empty list like pop
del partial[-1]

# Or to silently do nothing when applied to an empty list:
del partial[-1:]
```

which directly deletes the element without returning it.

None of these can be made to work with `str`, because `str` is immutable; it's impossible to modify aliases of the same `str` in place, you can only make new `str` and rebind a given name, which doesn't work for this case. An easy solution is to make your code that works with `str` convert it to either a `list`, or, if only ASCII/latin-1 characters occur in the `str` to encode it to `bytes` and then convert to `bytearray`, which *is* mutable and might allow you to use your code that expects mutable sequences more directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help - that makes sense!